# Craft Commerce: Editing Guest Address?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

While working with guest checkout in craft I noticed that the "Edit" address links were not available.

I removed {% if currentUser %} from the shipping template to reveal the edit links. Now when editing the billing address it also updates the shipping address - manipulating two different addresses does not seem possible.

This is the code for both edit links:

```
<a class="edit" href="/shop/checkout/customer/addresses/edit?addressId={{ cart.billingAddressId }}&redirect={{ craft.request.path }}">Edit</a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Guests do not have an address book so editing the address is not the right way to think about it. Logged in users can edit the addresses in their address book, but only one at a time.

If you want the guest user to change their addresses for the current cart, just use the data from the current cart addresses to populate the "commerce/cart/updateCart" form to submit 2 new addresses to the cart.

Let me know if you have further questions in the comments.

To edit a completed order's addresses, see this question: [Craft Commerce - Edit Complete Order Address from frontend](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21079/craft-commerce-edit-complete-order-address-from-frontend/21155#21155)